# How do you update a SQL record with ORDSYS.ORDImage in a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, error-handling

I'm trying to create a procedure that will update a column in my table with an ORDSYS.ORD Image. The code I have is bellow and it keeps telling me errors when I'm trying to use it. Can some please help? Thank you

Procedure code:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE Inserting_Images (REST_ID NUMBER, RESTImage ORDSYS.ORDImage) AS

  ctx RAW(64):=NULL;

BEGIN
  UPDATE restaurant_table
  Set RESTImage = RESTImage
  WHERE REST_id = REST_ID;


COMMIT;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN 
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    END;
--Error Handling.

END;
--Ends the procedure.

Using Procedure:
BEGIN
  inserting_images(52, 'YUSKIN.jpeg');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function Inserting_Images accepts an argument of ORDSYS.ORDImage, whereas what you are actually sending it is a VARCHAR, to get the behaviour you want, you need to initialize the ORDImage object first like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY FILE_DIR as '/mydir/work';
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY FILE_DIR TO 'user';
inserting_images(52, ORDSYS.ORDImage.init('FILE', 'FILE_DIR','speaker.jpg'));
```

(Quoted from docs.oracle.com)

Comment: Thank you for that, I really appreciate it. When I run the code now it says "anonymous block completed", but the field value still says NULL.

Comment: make sure you replace '/mydir/work' for the actual path to the folder containing the file, also replace 'user' for your user and 'speaker,jpg' for the name of your file

Comment: When I import the image, the ORDSYS.ORDImage properties of the record are all NULL. I constantly keep getting an error that says "22288. 00000 -  "file or LOB operation %s failed\n%s"
*Cause:    The operation attempted on the file or LOB failed." When Im trying to create a THUMBNAIL. Can you please help?